# Could not read commit log descriptor in file

Tags: cassandra, kundera

I started to use cassandra 3.7 and always I have problems with the commitlog. When the pc unexpected finished by a power outage for example the cassandra service doesn't  restart. I try to start for the command line, but always the error `cassandra could not read commit log descriptor in file` appears.

I have to delete all the commit logs to start the cassandra service. The problem is that I lose a lot of data. I tried to increment the replication factor to 3, but is the same.

What I can  do to decrease amount of lost data?

pd: I only one pc to use cassandra database, it is not possible to add more pcs.

Answer (score 0):

I think your option here is to work around the issue since its unlikely there is a guaranteed solution to prevent commit table files getting corrupted on sudden power outage. Since you only have a single node, it makes it more difficult to recover the data. Increasing the replication factor to 3 on a single node cluster is not going to help.

One thing you can try is to reduce the frequency at which the memtables are flushed. On flush of memtable the entries in the commit log are discarded, therefore reducing the amount of data lost. [Details here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html#reference_ds_qfg_n1r_1k__memtable_cleanup_threshold). This will however not resolve the root issue

Comment: I will try to modify this value in order to do that cassandra flush the memtable to disk more frequently. I have the database installed in a pc with 4gb ram, what would be the correct config?